# Representation of discrete random vector

Tags: probability

Good morning everyone.
I have a problem with a probability exercise.
I have a discrete random vector $(X, Y)$ uniformly distributed on the given set given triangle of vertices $(0,2), (0,0)$ and $(2,0)$.
I know that a random vector is discrete when I can represent it through a finite number of points.
Can I consider only the three points of the vertices or do I also have to take some points inside the triangle?
The exercise asks me to determine joint density and marginal densities

Comment: there's something wrong in how you have formulated the question. A variable cannot be at the same time discrete and uniformly distributed on a surface...

Comment: The trace of the exercise is: Let the discrete random vector (X, Y) be uniformly distributed over the set ... Determine the joint density and the marginal densities

Comment: over the set... ? Which set? I bet you're reading it wrong

Comment: the way I interpret the question is that $\mathbb P\{(X,Y)=(a,b)\}=\frac{1}{3}$ for all $(a,b)\in \{(0,2),(0,0),(2,0)\}$.

Comment: $A={(x,y): x \geq 0, y \geq0, 0\leq x+y\leq2}$

Comment: @Surb So are these 3 points enough?

Comment: It's how I interpret the exercise... is it the right way ? god knows...